# Cannot allocate resources due to URL rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting

I've a rewrite rule to convert [mysite.com/?lang=en](http://mysite.com/?lang=en) to [mysite.com/en](http://mysite.com/en), but this now gets me into troubles as the referenced files in the .html are relative to parent folder, and now its supossed to be /en/ instead of the root folder, how could I fix it?

PS: I think it has something to do with RewriteCond, but couldn't find the solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1. Write the assets in the source code with relative paths (use `../`) instead of absolute paths fromt he root.
2. Move all the assets in some specific folders, such as `images`, `stylesheets`, `assets`... then use mod_rewrite to rewrite `/LANG/folder` to `folder`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use RewriteCond to only do the rewrite for .html files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [.]html$
```